# What items are taken into consideration as registers during RTL coding?

Tags: verilog, register-transfer-level

module a(
input b;
output c;)
//registers to be selected during planning block diagrams
//eg: masking of interrupts, timeout register
endmodule

Comment: registers are supposed to keep their state after a value was applied to it. This is the only generic consideration. '

Comment: Your question is at risk of being closed for being unclear and too broad. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this 2 simple modules that invert 1 bit input:

1. In this one there is no register between input and output

   ```
   module inv(in, out);
       input  in;
       output out;
       assign out=~in; 
   endmodule
   ```

below there is a picture showing rtl translation of code:

[simple inverter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xw8t.png)

2. But in this one after inverting the input, this module register it and on the rising edge of clock signal put it as output:

   ```
   module inv(clk, in, out);
       input  in;
       input clk;
       output out;
       reg r;
       always @ (posedge clk)
          r <= ~in; 
       assign out=r; 
   endmodule
   ```

and below there is a picture showing rtl translation of code:

[simple inverter that register the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJjR2.png)